# What is off topic with this question?

Tags: discussion

This question: [Google's Index status falling down without any site changes](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59319/googles-index-status-falling-down-without-any-site-changes/59428?noredirect=1#59428)

What's off topic there?

I'm simply asking reason behind some Google's action.

My personal experience with this webmasters site is that to know whether my question will be closed or not is same as tossing a coin.

Answer (score 4):

I closed that question for several reasons:

1. You are asking us to review your site and tell you what is wrong.  We don't do that here.  If you want site reviews, I would recommend signing up for a  premium account at http://www.webmasterworld.com/
2. There is a more general question about why the number of indexed pages is falling.  That could reworked into a question that we could answer, but as it is, it is open ended, asking "What is the reason?"  This site is much better at answering specific questions such as "Is the reason X?".  We view opened ended questions as "unanswerable" and close them for that reason.
3. You don't give enough details about the problem.  We close questions that lack specifics as "unclear what you are asking".

When I close a question, I have to choose a reason and I chose the first.  To reopen the question, please edit it and correct all these problems.  When you edit the question, it will automatically enter the reopen queue and will be evaluated by members of this site to see if it should be reopened.

Comment: Where did you find my site URL, I never mentioned it nor sought any reviews from anybody. Secondly does Google let us know intricacies of their procedure? Where will I get information from to be of enough details. It shows you've closed it without even reading it.

Comment: I did think your URL was in there, so as it stands, I closed it for the wrong reason.  For that, I apologize.   I can't reopen it as it is though.  It is still open ended and unclear.